# Xpath and className are not working even though path and name are correct

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click "Action" button and select the option "Update Reference data".
[image: Actions button]
[image]

Here is my code

```
 Thread.sleep(30000);// To load the page
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"spend_mgmt_actions_menu\"]")).click();
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[id=\"upgradeRefData_button\"]")).click();
```

I also tried this, but got the same exception

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"spend_mgmt_actions_button\"]")));
driver.findElement(By.className("button show-right-icon f-dropdown-facade actions-list-button plan-action-button")).click();
Thread.sleep(20000);
```

But when I run the code it gives:

```
No Such Element Exception unable to locate.....
```

Below is the HTML code copied from browser by selecting the element.

```
<button id="spend_mgmt_actions_button"
class="button show-right-icon f-dropdown-facade actions-list-button plan-action-button"
aria-hidden="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-dropdown="spend_mgmt_actions_menu" tabindex="0">
<span>Actions</span><span class="icon icon-right fa fa-caret-down"></span></button>


 <button id="upgradeRefData_button" class="list-item dd-item" aria-disabled="false"
 data-dropdown-item="" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title=""><span>Update Reference Data</span>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. To `click()` on the element with text as **Actions** and then to `click()` the element with text as **Update Reference Data** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.button.show-right-icon.f-dropdown-facade.actions-list-button.plan-action-button#spend_mgmt_actions_button>span"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.list-item dd-item#upgradeRefData_button>span"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='button show-right-icon f-dropdown-facade actions-list-button plan-action-button' and @id='spend_mgmt_actions_button']/span[text()='Actions']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='list-item.dd-item' and @id='upgradeRefData_button']/span[text()='Update Reference Data']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I tried both the methods but none of them worked. I'm getting  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: button.button.show-right-icon.f-dropdown-facade.actions-list-button.plan-action-button#spend_mgmt_actions_button>span (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)  which is caused by Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector"...

Comment: @GauravBahadur _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _ExpectedConditions_. Debug your code through  `findElement()` inconjunction with `Thread.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.